# Type String is not a subtype of type CustomEvent error when trying to work with pixi package

Tags: json, dart, pixi.js

I have this code with which I am trying to load a spritesheet's associated JSON file...

```
class BunnyExample
{
  Renderer renderer    = new CanvasRenderer(width: 400, height: 300);
  Stage stage       = new Stage(new Colour.fromHtml('#ffffff'));
  Graphics graph = new Graphics();
  int drewLineCount = 0;

  BunnyExample()
  { 
    var assetsToLoad = ['sprites.json'];
    // Create a new loader.
    var loader = new AssetLoader(assetsToLoad);

     // Use callback.
     loader.onComplete.listen(onAssetsLoaded);

     // Begin load.
     loader.load();
    stage.children.add(graph);
    document.body.append(this.renderer.view);
  }

  void onAssetsLoaded(CustomEvent event) //Line 36 that stack trace references!
  {
    Sprite blah = new Sprite.fromFrame('wood_tile_2');
    blah.position = new Point(0,0);
    stage.children.add(blah);
  }
```

However when I run it on pub serve I get this error trace

```
Exception: Uncaught Error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'CustomEvent' of 'event'.
Stack Trace:
#0      onAssetsLoaded (http://localhost:8080/pixitest.dart:36:35)
#1      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1089)
#2      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341)
#3      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:595)
#4      _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:711)
#5      _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:671)
#6      _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#7      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
#8      _handleMutation (dart:html:40489)
```

I copied the general structure of the loading for [this example](https://github.com/FedeOmoto/pixi_examples/blob/master/web/2_sprite_sheet/index.dart)...can someone tell me what I've done wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `https://github.com/emergent-design/pixi.dart` as you can see in the code at `https://github.com/emergent-design/pixi.dart` the onComplete stream will return strings and not a CustomEvent. So changing `void onAssetsLoaded(CustomEvent event)` to `void onAssetsLoaded(_)` should work.